# Account Linking on Actions on Google

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home

I'm developing an action on Google that requires the user to login with my services. I was able to code the **linking account** (from [Implementing Account Linking](https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking) )

That works fine; I'm able to do the entire flow to authenticate the user using the Google Home app and my website (login, then redirect to google and return tokens, all happening inside the Google Home apn)

I already have an Android app (that uses the same tokens), so I want to be able to authenticate the user using the app (like `scheme://auth` or something like that)

Is there any way to have the authentication flow happens between the Google Home app and my own app instead of a website?

PS: You can't specify `scheme://` on the integration screen of **api.ai** (it should be https) but I was able to point that to a page in my server and then do a redirect to `scheme://` and opening my app. but at that point the flow ends

Comment: I have a similar problem, but i'd settle for just grabbing the key i need from the app data rather than authenticating. there would have to be a way to async call to my app or service. 

either that or broadcast an intent (or ios equivalent? no idea about ios) and handle it with my app/service, and somehow get back to the assistant with the key.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Currently, only the web auth flow is supported.

Comment: How to do Web auth flow for iOS app? Any suggestion?